# Generic parameter 'T' (self) could not be inferred

Tags: ios, generics, swift3

In the process of converting an iOS app to Swift 3.0, I am facing this type of issue.
The error message I get is this:

```
Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
```

But the code used to work fine. Can anyone see a problem?

Here is the relevant code:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, SomeProtocolOfMine {
    ........
    func buttonHandler(_ button: UIButton) {
            ........
            myImportantFunction(self)
    }
    ........
}


func myImportantFunction<T:UIViewController>(caller:T) where T:SomeProtocolOfMine {
    ........
    // Do something important and useful.
    ........
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you call that function using `myImportantFunction(caller: self)` or change the signagure to `...(_ caller: T)`?

Comment: Right! That was one of those details change brought by Swift 3.0, preventing from working things which used to work.
Anyway, in the meanwhile thanks a lot.